# Tried a used HDD in a HP Pavilion dv2 laptop, but it won't boot up, why?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bootable-media

I inserted the HDD, which does have **Window 8** installed on it, into the laptop. But it got stuck at a black screen. I could get into to the BIOS, but that was all.

When I booted the laptop with a USB, I saw the HDD just fine, reading, writing.

I can also use the HDD as an external HDD.

So it seems something about the booting, but what? 
The laptop is from 2009, the HDD is GPT formatted and just 2 years old 
I also tried booting the laptop with the HDD as an USB harddrive, but with the same result, no boot and a black screen.
The Windows 8 partition is NOT the first one on the disk, could that be a factor?

The HDD is a [ST1000LM024](https://www.google.com/search?q=ST1000LM024%20specifications&oq=ST1000LM024%20specifications&aqs=chrome..69i57.8776j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), specs:

```
Samsung Spinpoint M8
ST1000LM024 1TB
5400 RPM
8MB Cache
2.5" SATA 3.0Gb/s
```

Laptop [HP Pavilion dv2-1160](https://www.pcworld.com/article/162681/hp_pavilion_dv2.html):

```
1.6GHz AMD Athlon Neo Processor MV-40
2.00 GB 
Windows 7 Ultimate with Service Pack 1
12.1″ WXGA High-Definition HP LED BrightView Widescreen Display (1280×800)
HDD  320GB 5400RPM SATA
```

Comment: You cannot take a hard drive from one pc and stick it another and expect it to boot, you will have to reinstall the OS of your choice before it will boot.

Comment: Why not? Why would booting be dependent on the specific hardware? I'm looking for reasons. Any laptop or pc can be booted with USB's and CD's, so your comment seems flawed.  Also because of its **"just because I say so!"**-nature.

Comment: Windows only installs hardware-specific drivers, so attempting to boot to dissimilar hardware needs special preparation, replacing with generic drivers.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then how do you explain booting with repair USB's?  This HDD also has an OS installed on it.

Comment: 'special preparation' covers this. If you want to be able to swap drives from machine to machine, buy Macs; they can boot to any OS at least as new as themselves. Windows simply cannot do that. Google 'acronis universal restore' or 'dism sysprep' for ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop doesn't have UEFI and thus cannot boot from a GPT drive (well, it's from 2009, so no UEFI for you). You can only boot from a MBR drive.

Comment: This seems like a plausible answer.